# Finding the Greatest/Least value of String elements in a String array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've worked with arrays and know how to sort arrays that work with number values (double and int), but I have to make the same application using String arrays. My professor does not allow me to be "creative", or work with other static classes that might help to do the work.

I have to find the greatest value (in ASCII terms) of an array of String.
This is what I did:

```
public static String getGreatestValue(String[] StringArray) {

    String greatestValue = StringArray[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < StringArray.length; i++){
        for (int index= i+1; index < StringArray.length -1;  index++) {
            if (StringArray[i].compareTo(StringArray[index]) == 1)  
                greatestValue = StringArray[i];
        }
    }

    return greatestValue;
```

The list that I am working with in my Main Class looks like this:

```
package legacy;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[]args){

String[] names = {"D", "A", "B", "F"};

String greatestValue = StringArray.getGreatestValue(names);
System.out.println(greatestValue);
}
}
```

When I run the program it returns:

```
D
```

In this list the greatest value should be F.

I will be glad if someone finds a solution with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop. You should be comparing `StringArray[i]` to `greatestValue` (not to `StringArray[index]`). And you can start at `1` since you initialized `greatestValue` to `StringArray[0]`. Like,

```
String greatestValue = StringArray[0];
for (int i = 1; i < StringArray.length; i++){
    if (StringArray[i].compareTo(greatestValue) > 0) { // <-- or < 0 as appropriate
        greatestValue = StringArray[i];
    }
}
return greatestValue;
```

Finally, please respect Java variable naming conventions (`StringArray` looks like a class name, variables typically start with a lower case letter).

Comment: Holy sh#t! That was it? Omg I spent a whole two hours to get it! Thank you very much!

Comment: I will accept this answer as soon this allows me to do so.

Comment: Not only this. Take a look at my answer. You got problem in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is made because of two things. First of all you don't need nested loop. Second thing, is that you are checking if comparision is **equal** to 1. While you should check if it is higher or lower then 0 (depending on what you are comparing).

Here is working code:

```
public static String getGreatestValue(String[] StringArray) {

        String greatestValue = StringArray[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < StringArray.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(StringArray[i]);
                if (greatestValue.compareTo(StringArray[i]) < 0)
                    greatestValue = StringArray[i];
        }

        return greatestValue;
    }
```

Here you got examples how compareTo works with String:

```
System.out.println("A".compareTo("B")); //prints -1
System.out.println("A".compareTo("C")); //prints -2
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 provides a great way to do it:

`System.out.println(Arrays.stream(names).max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get());`

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr).max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get());`

Answer (score 0):

You're code does look a little bit too complicated. And it is recommned to begin variables with a lowercase character.

To your function, try:

```
public static String determineGreatest(String[] list) {
  String greatest = list[0];
  for (String cur: list) {
    if (cur.compareTo(greatest) >= 1) greatest = list[0];
  }
  return greatest;
}
```

You can use a similar method for determining the least string.